# Not able to find element by partial link text using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Using geckodriver 0.23.0, firefox 64.0.2, selenium 3.12, java 8  I'm not able to find the element by partial link text. A frame is not used. Link text is "**Accounts (1)**". There is only one other instance of the same text on the page "*View All Accounts*"

html:

```
<li>    
      <a href="/accounting/view_all_accounts?_t=039f18daf35b4a00f0093dd17aa70730be385f6f&amp;to_render=account" class="first accounting_page_menu  ">Accounts (1)</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/accounting/details?_t=e3d4ea94f5ed862d95196a620f1147be13b02979&amp;to_render=account" class="first accounting_page_menu ">Primary</a>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a onclick="javascript: ModalUtil.loadEditableModal('/accounting/details_new_account', false, false, true);" class="add-accounts">Add New Account...</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="/accounting/view_all_accounts?_t=039f18daf35b4a00f0093dd17aa70730be385f6f&amp;to_render=account" class="first accounting_page_menu ">View All Accounts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

The code I'm using to find the element: "Accounts (n)"  where n = 1, 2, 3 ...

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Accounts (")).click();
```

I tried with "**Accounts** " and with "**Accounts (**" and they both return the same 404 not found - no such element error

Console log:

```
1547499923019   webdriver::server   DEBUG   -> POST /session/bed7e7d2-d849-4bd0-ab17-fdca3fb080f9/element {
  "value": "Accounts ",
  "using": "partial link text"
}
1547499923020   Marionette  TRACE   0 -> [0,315,"WebDriver:FindElement",{"using":"partial link text","value":"Accounts "}]
1547499923241   Marionette  TRACE   0 <- [1,315,{"error":"no such element","message":"Unable to locate element: Accounts ","stacktrace":"WebDriverError@chrome://mario ... entError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:388:5\nelement.find/</<@chrome://marionette/content/element.js:339:16\n"},null]
1547499923240   webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 404 Not Found {"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"Unable to locate element: Accounts ","stacktrace":"WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178:5\nNoSuchElementError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:388:5\nelement.find/</<@chrome://marionette/content/element.js:339:16\n"}}
```

Comment: If finding "Accounts" by partial link text is not working, there's something wrong. Have you tried adding a wait? Are you sure there isn't an IFRAME? Are you sure of the capitalization?

Comment: Try running `$x("//a[.='Accounts (1)']")` in the dev console. Does it find anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you are trying to find the element with text as **Accounts (n)** where n = 1, 2, 3 ... and a couple of more elements with *linkText* as **Add New Account** and **View All Accounts** exists, instead of using `partialLinkText` it would be better to use *XPath* and you can use the following solution:

- *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li/a[@class='first accounting_page_menu' and starts-with(@href,'/accounting/view_all_accounts?')][starts-with(.,'Accounts')]"))).click();
  ```

---

### Update

As per the discussion [Official locator strategies for the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) **Partial link text selector** is preferred than **XPath selector**. However as per this *usecase* due to presence of similar *link texts* it would be easier to construct a *XPath*.

Comment: Good answer... yet is it better to use XPath then partialLinkText?

Comment: @MosheSlavin Added an update to the answer. Let me know if that answers your counter question.

Comment: I have seen this discussion hence my answer and comment... I must say I learn from you a lot!!! thanks

Comment: What confuses me regarding the partialLinkText is inability to locate a unique name: ----
Add New Account – does not have s at the end -> should not be catch by search “Accounts “ or “Accounts (“ ----
View New Accounts – does not have space at the end -> should not be catch by search “Accounts “ or “Accounts (“  ----
Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Ivana As you target text is `Accounts (n)`, targeting the partial text `Accounts` may include `Accounts (1)` and `View All Accounts` both. On the other hand I strongly would avoid `Accounts (` as the **`(`** can induce much chaos within the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890). Hence I would recommend _xpath_ or a _cssSelector_.